# tabs with 1 activity different views

Tags: android, tabs

I want to have 1 activity that is displayed on 2 tabs.

in my main I have the following:

```
    TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();  // The activity TabHost

    tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("tab0").setIndicator(tabNames[0]).setContent(R.id.tab0));
    tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("tab1").setIndicator(tabNames[1]).setContent(R.id.tab1));

    Intent intent = new Intent().setClass(this, DMXControllerActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
```

in my main.xml I have this inside the FrameLayout:

```
   <LinearLayout
       android:id="@+id/tab0"
       android:orientation="vertical"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent"
       android:padding="5dp">
    </LinearLayout>

   <LinearLayout
       android:id="@+id/tab1"
       android:orientation="vertical"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent"
       android:padding="5dp">
    </LinearLayout>
```

In my activity I have this:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    layoutTab0();
    layoutTab1();
```

}

private void layoutTab0() {

```
   LinearLayout ll_main = new LinearLayout(this);
   ll_main.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

    LinearLayout myll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab0);

    myll.addView(ll_main);

    LinearLayout ll_sliders = new LinearLayout(this);
    ll_sliders.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    ll_main.addView(ll_sliders);
```

......
.....
.....

}

when I start the app I see the contents of my tab0 and tab1 on top of each other.  When I hit the back key in the emulator I then see the 2 tabs as expected but they are empty.

How do I get my tabs contents to show up in on the tabs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to execute this code after setting the ContentView:

```
TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();  // The activity TabHost
tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("tab0").setIndicator(tabNames[0]).setContent(R.id.tab0));
tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("tab1").setIndicator(tabNames[1]).setContent(R.id.tab1));
```

Change your onCreate() to:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();  // The activity TabHost
    tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("tab0").setIndicator(tabNames[0]).setContent(R.id.tab0));
    tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("tab1").setIndicator(tabNames[1]).setContent(R.id.tab1));

    layoutTab0();
    layoutTab1();
}
```

In your code you're creating the tabs and then opening a new activity. If you don't open the activity the tabs will be present but they will be empty because you didn't add the content to them. You don't have to call a new activity, just add the content to the tablayouts and it should work.

Comment: The problem is that I create all of my controls dynamiclly in the activity not in an xml file.  I need to work with the various widgets in the activity so I need to create them there.  Before I had 1 activity in each tab but I had trouble transferring data back and forth between them. I thought having everythig in the same activity would be easier, the dat transfer is simple but now I can't get the gui layout to work right.

Comment: You don't have to use a xml file to use this code. In your code you're creating the tabs and then opening a new activity. If you don't open the activity the tabs will be present but they will be empty because you didn't add the content to them. You don't have to call a new activity, just add the content to the tablayouts and it should work.

Comment: Now you're understanding my answer, could you mark it as correct?